# HTTP request with authorization header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, http-headers

I'm going to ask a very simple question, yes it is really simple for every developer but not for beginner (maybe).

Let's me ask, **I want** to send HTTP request from browser when user click a button and I also want to add authorization header to the HTTP request.

I did this same thing with postman. In case of postman there are field to add headers to a request. But, how to do this same things with browser? I'm using node JS.

Comment: use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample code to make an HTTP Request using fetch:

```js
fetch('URL', { 
   method: 'post', 
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'YOUR_TOKEN', 
   }
 });
```